# Find and replace between html brackets with regular expressions

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, skip

Anyone can help me with a regular expression problem?

I want to find and replace between html tags
So, if I have

```
<p>hello</p> <i>bye bye</i>
```

I want to search and replace e to u for example. So the result would be

```
<p>hullo</p> <i>byu byu</i>
```

i think it’s easy to work around this problem, but i’m spending more time than i expected…

Thanks!

Comment: please share what you have tried.

Comment: man, these questions never end.

Comment: Use a parser, find all tags then do a string replace on the node contents.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer, @BurningCrystals!! 
I'm trying to edit an epub file. I'm using Sigil (http://sigil-ebook.com/) that implement regex search. But it's insane. I only want to replace inside brackets. Seems easy to solve, but as much i read, more difficult seems to solve that in an easy way.

Comment: Ok guys, i have the answer:

DO NOT USE REGEXP TO PARSE HTML. 

Question solved. I hated this problem tonight. Let's try another thing. Thanks a lot.